# Why the result of this regular expression in javascript is true?

Tags: javascript, regex

`alert(/[a-z]+/.test("4Nyth1n&_."));`

why the output is true? doesn't it supposed to match just the alphabet from a to z (lower case)?

Comment: The string contains `yth` and `n`. Looks like "the alphabet from a to z (lower case)" to me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) just looks for a match of a *sub*string. In this case, the substring `yth` matches. If you want to match the whole string, insert `^` and `$`:

```
alert(/^[a-z]+$/.test("4Nyth1n&_."));
```

Answer (score 2):

It matches because the test string contains a sub-sequence of chars from [a-z] 1 or more times, specifically "yth" and "n".